# Java MQQueueConnection get Client and Server versions

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm using ibm mq java libraries to connect to remote mq server.

Is it possible to know with version I'm using to connect from the java code?

I mean, given a MQQueueConnection, how can I get both, client libraries version and server side version?

I've been looking throught queueConnection.getMetaData(), but there are some data I don't understand.

Comment: You can check the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` for the MQ version the client jar came from.   If you run a IBM MQ JMS trace on the client you can find the queue manager version for anything later than 7.0 directly.   You can also likely see the FAP (protocol) version which can even give you a less specific idea of lower than 7.0 versions, ex FAP 4 = MQSeries 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be using the [com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) and [jms.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api) files with your project.

Note: The following ***ONLY*** works for MQ JAR files starting with IBM MQ V8.0 and later.  Otherwise, you will need to check the MQ JAR file's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` as JoshMc suggested.  And you really shouldn't be using old MQ JAR files.  See [IBM MQ End of Service Dates](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6525).

Hence, to find out what version of the MQ JAR files you are using, simply do the following command (go to the directory that contains the JAR files):

```
java -jar com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
```

And the output will look something like:

```
No options specified. Displaying all version information. Use java -jar com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar -help for usage information.
Name:        IBM MQ classes for Java Message Service
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production [Built on IBM Corporation  8.0.5.37 - pwa6480sr5fp37-20190618_01(SR5 FP37) Windows Server 2016]
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Name:        Common Services for Java Platform, Standard Edition
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Name:        Java Message Service Client
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Name:        IBM MQ JMS Provider
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709 mqjbnd=p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Name:        IBM MQ classes for Java
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
```

If you are using the individual MQ JAR files then you can issue the following command to get the MQ JAR version:

```
java -jar com.ibm.mq.jar
```

And the output will look like:

```
Name:        IBM MQ classes for Java
Version:     9.2.0.0
Level:       p920-L200709
Build Type:  Production
Location:    file:/F:/java/mq9.2.0.0_jars/com.ibm.mq.jar
```

Comment: Hi!, Thanks so much for your pov. And what about the server version? I have been looking at queueConnection.getMetaData().getProviderVersion(), but I'm not really sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To get info about the queue manager you are connected with a JMS 1.x app, this can be used:

```
Connection connection = cf.createConnection(userid, password);
JmsPropertyContext propertyContext = (JmsPropertyContext) connection;
int level = propertyContext.getIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_COMMAND_LEVEL);
```

And then `level` will be something like  `MQConstants.MQCMDL_LEVEL_922`

If you want to get more granular to the fixpack level on the qmgr, then something like a PCF query might be needed to get the MQCA_VERSION attribute.